# What is this if statement checking?

Tags: c

This is a function I obtained from class. I am just confused with the flow control here. The first `if` statement checks if there is the function and at least one argument. The second `else if` flow control, to my understanding, is checking if `argv[1]` is NOT a `NULL` pointer. My question is, if the first flow control is passed, would that mean the second flow control will definitely pass? How do we reach the third flow control in this case? Is my understanding of the second flow control incorrect?

```
int my_function(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"not enough arguments" );
        return(1);
    }
    else if (argv[1]) 
        return(atoi(argv[1])); 
    else 
        exit(0);

}
```

~

Comment: Note that the `else if` condition should always be true, since `argc` is at least 2 if it gets there, in which case `argv[1]` will be non-NULL.  So you can just replace it with an `else`, and get rid of the existing `else`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *if-else if-else* ladder. Only one of this will run at a time.

So, if you send less than 2 arguments (if case), "not enough arguments" will be printed and `my_function()` will return 1, which denoted an error condition.

If you send more than 2 arguments (`argc >= 2`), and `argv[1]` isn't `NULL` (else-if case), `my_function()` will return `atoi(argv[1])`.

Finally, if both the above conditions are false, i.e., if `argc >= 2 && NULL == argv[1]`, `my_function()` will return 0. Now this is incorrect in my opinion, since returning 0 means success, which is clearly not the case here.

EDIT: Now the code exits in the else case, which seems to be OK.

Comment: Does argc include the `NULL` terminator?

Comment: It's an `int`, why do you think it should?

Comment: I understand. What I mean is does argc count the `NULL` terminator as well? I edited the function btw. The goal of the function is suppose to exit the `main` function which calls on `my_function`. Last question, does `if(argv[1])` check if it is `NULL` or not `NULL`?

Comment: I've already answered about the NULL check in the answer. As far as NULL terminator for `argc` is concerned, it is not applicable since it is an `int`. NULL terminator is only for `char *` types.

Comment: It should be pointed out that if `argc` is >= 2, then `argv[1]` will be non-NULL, so there is no need to make that test.  At best it should be an assertion, but even that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct -- the `else if` statement is checking to see if `argv[1]` is not `NULL`.

If `argc` and `argv` are the same parameters that are passed into `main()` by the runtime library, then `argv[1]` will never be NULL when `argc >= 2`, so the final `else` is unreachable code.  However, if this function is called with parameters that are obtained elsewhere, then there is no such guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

You would be correct if that function were `main`.  The only way that `argv[1]` wouldn't be true would be if `argc < 2`.  So you could never reach the third branch.

But since it's a separate function, you *could* do the following, and the third branch would trigger.

```
int main(void) {
    char *argv[] = { NULL, NULL };
    int r = my_function(42, argv); // r == 0
}
```

(Of course, no sane coder would give a function `argc` and `argv` parameters without also making them have the same semantics as `main`'s.)

Comment: "(Of course, no sane coder would..."   Famous last words :-)

Comment: @cbranch Yeah, I know.  I considered adding a phrase about just how often people have probably done this, but decided to just leave it as an implied "so *please* don't do this yourself".

Comment: No worries -- your point is valid, but I just couldn't resist having a little fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right, assuming the "usual" semantics of `argc` and `argv`.  Under the standard interpretation of `argv` and `argc` in a `main()` function, the third clause is very unlikely to ever be reached.

If `argc >= 2`, then `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` point to null-terminated `char*` strings, and `argv[2]` is a NULL pointer.  The only way `argv[1]` would be a NULL pointer is if `argc == 1` ... which is already caught by the first if condition!

I suppose this could be seen as very safe coding, but if things are that badly screwed up I would just let it crash.